# create .RDP file with unmodifiable parameters

Tags: rdp

I want to save a Remote Desktop file, but after saved I want it maintain the parameters I provided unmodified.

Is it possible?

Thank you very much

Daniel

Comment: Can you state the purpose?  Is this just for your use, or are you intending to distribute a config .RDP file to users?

Comment: I think this is a reasonable request. Having a .rdp file in the "All Users" desktop location is a viable way to deploy a link to a Terminal Server for instance.

Comment: We make the whole All Users profile read-only to non-admins.  Another approach is to create a read-only folder (NTFS permissions)(I frequently create C:\Custom for various tweaks, but you could use Program Files), put the RDP file there, and create shortcuts to it. The shortcuts can go into user-editable locations and the underlying RDP file will be unmodifiable.

Answer (score 5):

An .RDP file is merely a text file with parameters.  It is normally easy to edit either with a text editor, or via the RDP client: mstsc.exe.

You could use file permissions to make it read-only.

If you're using robust Remote Desktop infrastructure (**Connection Broker**, **RDWeb**), you can essentially obscure the .RDP files by using start menu links (**RemoteApp and Desktop Connections Control Panel** integration in Windows 7+)